# Identify difference in 2 data frame with missing values

Tags: r

Suppose I have 2 data frames:

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=2:6)
a2 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=c(2:5,NA))
```

I would like to identify which columns are not identical (I will need the column number later). I thought that this would do the trick:

```
apply(!a1==a2, 2, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

However, because the last entry in a2 is an NA, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're using `sum`, but to  identify which columns are not identical you could use `mapply` with `identical` and negate the result.

```
which(!mapply(identical, a1, a2))
# b 
# 2
```

for the column number.  Or more simply for use in a column subset

```
!mapply(identical, a1, a2)
#     a     b 
# FALSE  TRUE
```

Just as a note, the word *identical* has a meaning in R that may be different from the result of `==`, so it's possible you may need to clarify your question a bit.

```
x <- 1
y <- 1L
x == y
# [1] TRUE
identical(x, y)
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use `sum`, you could try

```
  colSums(a1==a2, na.rm=TRUE)!=nrow(a1)
  #  a     b 
  #FALSE  TRUE
```

Or using your code

```
 apply(a1==a2, 2, sum, na.rm=TRUE)!=nrow(a1)
 #  a     b 
 #FALSE  TRUE
```